# Proving a cardinality inequality by checking there's an injective function: Problem 4.1.4 in Introduction to Set Theory Hrbáček and Jech

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The question is prove: $$\lvert A\rvert\ \leq \lvert A^s\rvert.$$

My attempted solution: Since $S \neq \emptyset$, we can plug some $$s \in S.$$ So consider $$f: A \to A^s$$ where $$f(x) = b.$$

I am having trouble finding the correct function. I believe I can prove injectivity.

EDIT: I have If $$S \neq \emptyset,$$ then we can choose some $$a \in S.$$ Consider $$f: A \to A^s$$ where $$f_a(s) = a$$ for all $$a \in S.$$ Let $$g: a \to f_a.$$ To see g is injective, let $$a, a' \in A.$$ and $$a \neq a.$$ Then $$g(a) = f_a \neq f_{a'} = g(a').$$ QED.

Comment: Please don't put everything in display mode; or, if you do, then please put the punctuation inside display mode.  I have edited accordingly. \\ What does $A^s$ mean?  What are $x$ and $b$?

Comment: For b, I was trying to make a constant function (like the book hinted at it) and that's what I believe your hinting when talking about element s. $$A^s$$ is the set of functions $$s \to A$$.

Comment: The reason I deleted the other post was because I talked to my professor about it afterwards. You may some good points, but my professor was looking for another method (he said that way wasn't going to work in that scenario.) That was just a really hard problem, but I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, I just started posting on math stack exchange. I learned that you have to use double dollar signs when writing any math symbols.

Comment: It is not correct that you have to use double dollar signs when writing any math symbols.  Rather, you should use double dollar signs for equations in "display mode"; this is a large mode intended to bring particular attention to special equation.  For ordinary math symbols, you should use "math mode", which is offset with single dollar signs.  If you roll back to my edit, you will see that it renders just fine.

Comment: Alright, I keep that in mind. I got what I said somewhere from math stack exchange guidance. But I must have misremembered the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I see you just added a new proof to your question, and it is the same as what I wrote below. :)

$A^S$ is the set of functions $f:S\to A$.

We want an injection $A\to A^S$, so we want to find a distinct function $f_a\in A^S$ for each $a\in A$.

So, the "obvious" choice is to let $f_a:S\to A$ be the constant function that sends $s\mapsto a$ for each $s\in S$. These functions are distinct when $S\neq\varnothing$, because for any $s\in S$ we have $f_a(s)=a\neq b=f_b(s)$ if $a\neq b$. We need at least one $s\in S$ for this to be observed, though, since $A^\varnothing=\{\varnothing\}$ contains only the empty function.